# How to use inequalities in julia with SymPy

Tags: julia, sympy, inequalities

How to use inequalities in julia with SymPy?
no does works:

```
using SymPy 
@syms x 
ineq = (x+1)/(x-1) >=0
```

Comment: Use `Ge`, as in`Ge((x+1)/(x-1), 0)`. For convenience, the unicode operator `\geqq[tab]` may be used infix. (Some explanation is in the `piecewise` documentation.

Comment: Hi  jverzani  . Thanks for this ;). I used Ge, Gt, Eq, Le, Lt, from his tip.